# how to randomize column data and mask data using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

DISCLAIMER: NONE OF THESE VALUES ARE TRUE/REAL, ITS JUST A PRACTICE ASSIGNMENT

how to randomize the last 6 digits of the DBS account and obscuring the first 4 digits of the NRIC number with x using mysql. All values were keyed in manually and do not relate to each other.

Current

[image: the mysql]

Desired Result
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Do you mean how to change the database or how to change those values as part of a SELECT query?

Comment: change those values and update the database

Comment: Does DBS-ACCOUNT contain anything trick like a check digit or is there no relationship at all between the nodes?

Comment: there is no relationship

Comment: Again, ___change those values___ DO you want to UPDATE those values on this table, forever! Or do you want to SELECT these values and obfiscate those column values just as part of a query

Comment: Are any of these real Singapore NRICs or DBS account numbers?  If so, then please delete them from your question ASAP.

Comment: Update the values in the table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nope, its just a random set of questions for a project

Comment: Random does not mean unique but if it's for a project and dbs_account does not have  unique key and is not used in a fk then I guess it doesn't matter if you get duplicates?

Comment: yea it doesnt matter as long its randomize

Comment: Please use copy/paste instead of adding images!

Answer (score 0):

Just use substring operations:

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT('XXXX', SUBSTRING(NRIC, 5, 4)) AS NRIC,
    Name,
    Contact,
    Salary,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(DBS_Account, 1, 3), '-XXXXX-X') AS DBS_Account
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql rand function - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

using substring and concat

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(RAND(),3,5),'-',SUBSTRING(RAND(),3,1))
```

will give something like 40033-8

then concat with substring

```
set @a ='038-12645-6';
SELECT CONCAT(substring_index(@a,'-',1),'-',SUBSTRING(RAND(),3,5),'-',SUBSTRING(RAND(),3,1));

'038-63475-5'
```